# A generic byte response type?

Tags: java, rest, http

I am writing a RESTful service that returns an array of bytes. I know of several response types associated with HTTP, including text/html, application/xml, and image/png (among several others). I am unaware of a response type that would be associated with a generic array of bytes.

Does such a response type exist? I don't want to send the bytes as text, and none of the image types seem appropriate. Is there a kind of "byte" type that represents an array of bytes?

Someone please advise...

Comment: depends on what the byte array is of? image, pdf, video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`application/octet-stream`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream) is registered with IANA for this purpose:

> The "octet-stream" subtype is used to indicate that a body contains
>   arbitrary binary data.

It is actually defined in [RFC 2046](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt), section 4.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can send binary data using 'application/octet-stream`.

Here is a full [list of MIME Content-Types](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)