# How to display Image received as BufferedImage in Java server api in Angular 10

Tags: java, angular, microsoft-graph-api

I have an api that calls Microsoft Graph and receives a user's photo. I am not sure how to read this api call in Angular to actually display the photo.

**Java:**

```
public BufferedImage getUserPhoto (String accessToken) throws IOException {

    IAuthenticationProvider mAuthenticationProvider;

    try{
        mAuthenticationProvider=request->request.addHeader("Authorization",accessToken);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Error("Could not create a graph client: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    graphClient=
            GraphServiceClient.builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(mAuthenticationProvider)
                    .buildClient();

    InputStream stream = 
         graphClient
            .me()
            .photo()
            .content()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();

    System.out.println("Stream"+ stream);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);

    return image;
}
```

**Angular**

```
getUserPhoto(){
    return this.httpClient.get(`${API_URL}/graph/getPhoto`);
  };
```

**EDIT**: I figured it out.
I converted the Buffered Image into a Base64 String and then received that in angular and displayed.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String  imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);
        bos.close();
```

Angular

```
  getPhoto(){
    return this.httpClient.get(`${API_URL}/graph/getPhoto`,{ responseType: "text" });
  }


  public getUserPhoto(){
    this.graphService.getPhoto().subscribe(
      response => {
        let objectURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response;
        this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
      });
  }
```

Comment: `<img [src]="photoPath">` should work. just put photoPath with the right path on the component

Comment: Iam sorry, can you elaborate a bit more?
iI am getting error:
GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @nabeelh21 try to view this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044110/how-to-display-images-in-web-page-using-angularjs. 
You have a problem with conversion i think.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `InputStream` to `byte array`. Then display byte array as image in angular.

`getUserPhoto()` function with Microsoft Graph SDK:

```
public byte[] getUserPhoto() throws IOException {

    String CLIENT_ID = "";
    List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("scope1", "scope2");
    String CLIENT_SECRET = "";
    String TENANT_GUID = "";
    String userId = "";

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_GUID, NationalCloud.Global);
    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

    InputStream stream = graphClient.users(userId).photo().content().buildRequest().get();
    byte[] imageArray = new byte[stream.available()];
    stream.read(imageArray);

    return imageArray;
}
```

Note: I use the ClientCredentialProvider which needs application permissions. You could refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth#22-create-an-authentication-provider-object).

My Pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Display byte array as image in angular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391591/13308381

```
var bytes = [ ... ]; // get from server
var uints = new UInt8Array(bytes);
var base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(null, uints));
var url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64; // use this in <img src="..."> binding
```

Comment: When I convert the InputStream to a byte[] and print to console, it is showing up as [B@5bb14560

Comment: Also, what is the response type in Angular for receiving this api call from the server?

Comment: How do you print the byte[], with `System.out.println(imageArray);` or `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(imageArray));`? The response type is [application/octet-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927169/13308381).